# Multiplication of complex numbers using AVX2+FMA3

Tags: c, simd, complex-numbers, avx2

I have found some solutions where each AVX2 register holds both, the real and imaginary part of the complex numbers. I am interested in a solution where each AVX2 registers holds either the real or the imaginary part.
Assuming we have 4 AVX2 registers:`R1, I1, R2, I2`

Registers `R1, I1` form 4 complex numbers. Same applies for the remaining two registers. Now I want to multiply the 4 complex numbers of `R1, I1` with the 4 complex numbers of `R2, I2`. What would be the most efficient way to do this? Besides AVX2, FMA3 can be used as well.

Comment: This is actually more simpler than the case when register holds both real and img part. You may also have to define two more vectors `out_real` and `out_img` for storing the output. For the real part multiply `R1*R2` and store it in `out_real`. Then do the fuse negative multiplication and addition(fnmadd) of `-(I1*I2) + out_real`. Similar approach for the imaginary part.

Comment: Is this about element-wise multiplication or all-pairs multiplication that results  in 16 values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote you have AVX2, all Intel and AMD AVX2 processors also support FMA3. For this reason, I would do it like that.

```
// 4 FP64 complex numbers stored in 2 AVX vectors,
// de-interleaved into real and imaginary vectors
struct Complex4
{
    __m256d r, i;
};

// Multiply 4 complex numbers by another 4 numbers
Complex4 mul4( Complex4 a, Complex4 b )
{
    Complex4 prod;
    prod.r = _mm256_mul_pd( a.r, b.r );
    prod.i = _mm256_mul_pd( a.r, b.i );
    prod.r = _mm256_fnmadd_pd( a.i, b.i, prod.r );
    prod.i = _mm256_fmadd_pd( a.i, b.r, prod.i );
    return prod;
}
```

Or if you targeting that [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_VIA_Nano_microprocessors#Nano_C) VIA processor which doesn’t have FMA, replace the FMA intrinsics with the following lines:

```
prod.r = _mm256_sub_pd( prod.r, _mm256_mul_pd( a.i, b.i ) );
prod.i = _mm256_add_pd( prod.i, _mm256_mul_pd( a.i, b.r ) );
```

Comment: *all AVX2 processors also support FMA3* - Unfortunately no, there's one VIA CPU which doesn't, much to the chagrin of at least one of the architects.  That's a really rare corner case, though, so either just list AVX2+FMA3 as requirements, or if your code checks CPU features and uses a fallback, then have it require FMA3 as well for this.  Of course this just requires FMA3 + AVX1, like AMD Piledriver, although 256-bit load/store is a performance disaster on Piledriver so maybe just require AVX2+FMA3 to intentionally exclude AMD Bulldozer-family, if you don't care about steamroller/excavator.

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting, I didn’t know about that VIA. Updated.

Comment: Changed the question to include FMA3. But good point on this.